# Message - Cannot find installed version of python-django or python3-django

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm new to Ubuntu, and I love it so far. I have been trying to install Django for a website development project.
In the terminal, when I start the python interpreter and type

```
import django 
django.VERSION
```

I face no issues and get

```
(1, 8, 2, 'final', 0)
```

Then, to start my project, I typed

```
django-admin startproject trialsite
```

and I got a message saying

```
Cannot find installed version of python-django or python3-django
```

I installed django using `pip install Django==1.8.2` and also installed the django-admin package before using it via apt-get. Also, I have been following the Django book as a guide through the whole process. Can someone tell me what the issue is?

My `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` and `site-packages` are both empty. I don't know if this is important. But according to the django book, this is where `django-admin` should be.

Comment: using it via apt-get?

Comment: I meant to say that I installed django-admin using sudo apt-get install django-admin.

Comment: @LM10 - Please add your answer to an Answer block. Don't add them to your Question. Once you have a correct answer that solves your problem, click the green checkmark. Its OK to accept your own answer. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use following command and it will be solved.

```
sudo apt-get install python-django
```

Comment: worked for me, but why installing with 'sudo pip3 install django' was giving the error 'Cannot find installed version of python-django or python3-django.' when i tried to run django-admin command?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **tcsh** as I was to run django-admin, my shell did not have the "$_" environment variable. After creating it as follows, I was able to get django-admin running.

```
% set _ = (/usr/bin/env) 

% django-admin --version
1.11.3
```

You can add $_ to your .tcshrc file so it loads in your profile automatically.